# Solving linear system of equations with three variables to obtain ranked prestige: how to?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, artificial-intelligence

Whatever I do, I can't grasp it. The letters confuses me, as I don't know exactly what I need to do.

For example, I get **z = 14 / 15 y**, but what's next? Should I plug the whole y function once again in z?

Could someone give me a step by step solution for this one? I want to understand it, yet I can't grasp it somehow. Have an exam tomorrow andddd this is driving me nuts.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your equations are homogeneous.  Any solution can be multiplied by any constant and get another solution.  You can choose any variable to be any value you want and derive the other two.  As you have correctly found $z=\frac {14}{15}y$ and the first equation says $x=\frac 15y$ we can choose $y=1$ and get a solution $$x=\frac 15\\y=1\\z=\frac {14}{15}$$  Any multiple of this is also a solution.  The information of interest is that $y$ is the highest with $z$ close behind.

Comment: What I don't get is... how is y = 1? Y consists of x and z, so how can I just throw away everything it says and assume it's 1? The solution model says x = 5y btw, not 1/5.

Comment: Equation (1) says $x=\frac 15 y,$ not $5y$.  As I said, any multiple of a solution is another solution.  You can double my answers and plug the results in to check.  Your three equations have redundancy in them, so there are really only two equations there.

Comment: Each equation reduces the solution set by one dimension.  You start with all of $\Bbb R^3$, then apply each equation.  As there are only two independent equations here, the solution set is a line.  Because there are no constants in the equations, the line goes through the origin.  You can pick any one variable to be whatever value you choose, then the other two are determined.